# how to manage Zip file to mail in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am create zip file of document folder  i want know that how to remove sqlite file from zip only i need other file in zip but it giving all file which is holding by document folder directory to zip i dont want sqlite file in zip file

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    BOOL isDir=NO;
    NSArray *subpaths;
    NSString *exportPath = docDirectory;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];    
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:exportPath isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir){
        subpaths = [fileManager subpathsAtPath:exportPath];
    }

    NSString *archivePath = [docDirectory stringByAppendingString:@".zip"];

    ZipArchive *archiver = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
    [archiver CreateZipFile2:archivePath];
    for(NSString *path in subpaths)
    {
        NSString *longPath = [exportPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
        if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:longPath isDirectory:&isDir] && !isDir)
        {
            [archiver addFileToZip:longPath newname:path];      
        }
    }
    BOOL successCompressing = [archiver CloseZipFile2];
    if(successCompressing)
        NSLog(@"Success");
    else
        NSLog(@"Fail");





    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;




    NSString *emailBody =@""; 
    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

    [picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"" fileName:@"Document.Zip"];
```

Answer (score 0):

What you would do is create an NSData object with dataWithContentsOfFile:, with a path to the zip archive, then set the mime type to application/zip.